# What are the things you look for when using EXPLAIN ANALYZE to determine if there are improvements you can make or not

Tags: postgresql

I've been reading up a bunch of the Postgres docs, but it's still not super clear to me when looking at the output if the query is optimized, or not. I've tried adding some indexes, which has reduced the number of lines in the output. If you were to look at something like this:

```
 Limit  (cost=26.16..26.18 rows=10 width=322) (actual time=0.077..0.079 rows=10 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=26.16..26.19 rows=12 width=322) (actual time=0.076..0.077 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: like_count DESC, inserted_at DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on comments c0  (cost=4.40..25.94 rows=12 width=322) (actual time=0.036..0.049 rows=38 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((post_id = 'dc1ab68f-db3f-4b45-aa48-b5c30298e261'::uuid) AND (parent_id IS NULL))
               Heap Blocks: exact=9
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on comments_post_id_parent_id_index  (cost=0.00..4.40 rows=12 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=38 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((post_id = 'dc1ab68f-db3f-4b45-aa48-b5c30298e261'::uuid) AND (parent_id IS NULL))
 Planning Time: 0.099 ms
 Execution Time: 0.099 ms
(11 rows)
```

Are there any key things you look at to say "This query is pretty optimized", or "Wow, there's an index I can add to reduce all that work"?

Comment: 0.099 **milli**seconds seems pretty fast to me. How fast do you need that to be?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'd notice is that it took less than 1/10,000 of a second to run, and so is unlikely to need manual optimization work.  And then I'd wonder, why did I get started looking at such a fast query in the first place?  Surely I should be examining the slow queries, not the fast ones.

Comment: This was after running the command 5-6 times, so this was in a fully cached state. Do you usually prefer the scores on the first run, or after it's had time to cache?

Comment: @PeterR That is hard to answer in general.  On a production system, I would usually turn track_io_timing on and use auto_explain with log_analyze and log_buffers on (but with log_timing off if I were on a system with slow user access to the system clock) to see what was happening under actual conditions. On test or dev, I would probably run it repeatedly, but with a different value for post_id each time.  That way buffers used in common would be cached, but ones specific to a given post_id would not be cached, which seems most realistic.

Answer (score -1):

I first look for sequential table scans which indicate that the query planner could not use an index either because there isn't one, or it has failed to use it for some reason.

Comment: Is a `Bitmap Heap Scan` different from a table scan?

Comment: Yes. A sequential scan iterates over the actual rows looking for those that satisfy the query. In some cases a seq scan is appropriate especially for small tables or for queries that would return a large number of rows anyway.

Comment: So if I have an index on `(post_id, parent_id)`, why would it do a Bitmap Heap Scan, instead of an index scan?